# Linked list C program unexpected behaviour in conditional statement

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was executing below linked list program,but this code is behaving in an unexpected way ,when i compared head with NULL it dont executes if() block and reaches to else block ,  but inside if() condition if i put a statement like printf(""); and after I run program upon comparision of head==Null if() block gets executed .I tried one more modification if i removed head=new; from else part and also removed printf("") statement as well then if() condition gets executed iam unable to understand why it is behaving this way can anyone tell me.Thank you

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    struct node
    {
     struct node *prev;
     int data;
     struct node *next;

    };
    struct node *head;

    void createB(int item)
    {
     struct node *newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     newnode->prev=NULL;
      newnode->next=NULL;
     newnode->data=item;

     if(head==NULL)  //upon compairing it reaches to else 
                     //block i debugged in turbo c as well and head is NULL
     {
       head = newnode;
              }
     else
     {
      newnode->next=head;
      head->prev=newnode;
      head=newnode;
             }
                      }
    main()
     {
    createB(2);
      }
```

Comment: You must initialize `head` to `NULL`, otherwise think of it having an arbitrary (illegal!) value.

Comment: already tried that as well nothing changes behaviour remains same :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it works after you initialize head properly. Did you recompile? You should also use a debugger and observe the values while you step through the program.

Comment: Iam 100% sure i checked this many times previously by debugging its behaviour remains  same sir

Comment: here is image here I used NULL but flow remains same https://pasteboard.co/JaDw4Rv.png

Comment: Just to be sure that we talk about the same: you say that your (first and only) call in main `createB(2)` results in taking the `else` branch although you initialized `head = NULL`?

Comment: yes we re talking same :)

Comment: In below link there is code where i inserted printf("") inside if() block now control reached if() block  https://pasteboard.co/JaDybMd.png

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/AaxEim so you tell me basically that this code prints "ELSE" on your system? If so: you're compiler is seriously broken.

Comment: the link you have provided csn you try removing the printf statements both from if() and else() then it should go to else part , iam not getting how to debug there is it possible in that compiler , thank you

Comment: Why in heaven should it jump to the `else` branch when I just remove the printf statements?? Either you misunderstood something or you are doing something very wrong. https://godbolt.org/z/ZJJc7q now I removed the printf statements and added one in main to see that it worked. Sure, we now can no longer really know which branch was taken, but I guarantee you that it was the `if` branch.

Comment: hi thanks for your help , looks like there is some issue in my turbo c compiler , thanks again :)